# Where to find uctypes micropython module

Tags: micropython, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm working with circuitpython, and need access to the micropython uctypes module. I've downloaded the micropython files from github, but can't seem to find the module. Can anyone help?

Comment: Which port / board are you using?

Comment: Metro M4 Express equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [CircuitPython issue](https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython/issues/1067): this is a known thing, and it looks like none of the ports actually have the uctypes module enabled: for that, the `MICROPY_PY_UCTYPES` preprocessor definition must be non-zero when building and this is normally set in the port's mpconfigport.h but that is not the case here.

So either you'll have to build yourself (see e.g. https://learn.adafruit.com/building-circuitpython/) and either add said definition into mpconfigport.h or pass it on the commandline, or find an alternative solution (same link mentions the `struct` module could be used instead, which it might indeed depending on the exact usecase).

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction. I've tried defining and building, but now I'm receiving other errors of header files not being included and other warnings.

Comment: I'm somewhat under the impression that the module is not yet ready for use, as I shouldn't need to include the -Wall cflag in order to build it.

Comment: You might want to pick this up with Circuitpython and create an issue on github

Answer (score 0):

To enable uctypes in CircuitPython 7.0, try the following patch.  It worked for me.

```
--- extmod/moductypes.c.orig    2021-11-27 00:07:08.000000000 +0900
+++ extmod/moductypes.c 2021-11-27 00:11:13.000000000 +0900
@@ -544,7 +544,7 @@
             }
 
         } else if (agg_type == PTR) {
-            byte *p = *(void **)self->addr;
+            byte *p = *(void **)((void *)self->addr);
             if (mp_obj_is_small_int(t->items[1])) {
                 uint val_type = GET_TYPE(MP_OBJ_SMALL_INT_VALUE(t->items[1]), VAL_TYPE_BITS);
                 return get_aligned(val_type, p, index);
@@ -574,7 +574,7 @@
                 mp_int_t offset = MP_OBJ_SMALL_INT_VALUE(t->items[0]);
                 uint agg_type = GET_TYPE(offset, AGG_TYPE_BITS);
                 if (agg_type == PTR) {
-                    byte *p = *(void **)self->addr;
+                    byte *p = *(void **)((void *)self->addr);
                     return mp_obj_new_int((mp_int_t)(uintptr_t)p);
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Thank you, I've moved away from using uctypes for the present, but will be helpful for the future.